# Automatic adding data from excel to table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I would like load data from excel file to table. The problem is that I would like do it evry day, because data are adding to excel file in each day.

I have no problem with write script which will add data from excel to table (I use LOAD FILE) but I have problem with automatic launching these script. Is it possible in MySQL (best in MySQL WorkBench)? I need some materials, because I have never done it. I will grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

use VBscript to call excel macro that fill the data to file then use solway's task scheduler (freeware) to execute the VBscript
for connecting to mysql via VBScript use the following

Install MySQL Connector/ODBC 5.1 and use a connection string like the following

```
connectionString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=yourServerAddress;Database=yourDataBase;User=yourUsername; Password=yourPassword;"
```